java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: CreationExtras must have a value by `SAVED_STATE_REGISTRY_OWNER_KEY`
sToday I've upgraded some libraries then I started the app and when I click the button that is navigation button , I got this error  :

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: CreationExtras must have a value by SAVED_STATE_REGISTRY_OWNER_KEY

Libraries ;
implementation("androidx.core:core-splashscreen:1.0.1")

    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.7.0")
    implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.8.2")
    implementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2024.04.00"))
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.2.1")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.7.7")

    implementation("com.google.code.gson:gson:2.10.1")
    implementation("androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.1.0-alpha01")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-compose:2.8.0-alpha04")


    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
    androidTestImplementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2024.04.00"))
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest:1.7.0-alpha06")

    //Arrow
    implementation("io.arrow-kt:arrow-core:1.2.4")
    implementation("io.arrow-kt:arrow-fx-coroutines:1.2.4")

    //Coil
    implementation("io.coil-kt:coil-compose:2.6.0")

    //DataStore
    implementation("androidx.datastore:datastore-core:1.1.0-rc01")
    implementation("androidx.datastore:datastore-preferences:1.0.0")

    //dagger hilt
    implementation("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.51.1")
    kapt("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.51.1")



    //PostgreSQL
    implementation("org.postgresql:postgresql:42.7.3")

    //Calendar Dialog
    implementation("com.maxkeppeler.sheets-compose-dialogs:calendar:1.3.0")


    implementation ("androidx.graphics:graphics-shapes:1.0.0-alpha05")

Bad side is I don't remember versions that is before upgraded
I saw a question then I tried solutions but didn't work . Please help me I can't continue my project right now. And I tried some old version to check version conflicts.But still there is a problem. I couldn't understand. :(
And I saw some solutions that is about error comes from navigation-compose or hilt-navigation-compose version but I tried all of them. They didn't work.
By the way I've upgraded my AGP version 8.3.2 from old version.I don't remember old version

Finally I've found the problem.It is from postgreSQL-jdbc version.If you are using JDBC with postgre you shouldn't use last version.last version is 42.7.3 in these days but I used 42.2.9 and problem was solved.

Please add more details on

Why should you should not use the latest version for postgreSQL-jdbc?
Why/How did downgrading the version from 42.7.3 to 42.2.9 solve your issue?


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Last versions is 42.7.3 it has problem when it's working with other libraries.I had seen from somewhere this 42.2.9 is good optimized version.That's why I did
